# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension when installing Sablon gem

Tags: ruby

I am trying to install and use the Sablon ruby gem. I have installed xcode command line developer tools. However, I continue to get the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing sablon:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.1.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
```

Any ideas as to what might be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

try

`gem install sablon -- --use-system-libraries=true`

if it doesn't work may i ask how you installed xcode command line tools?